# Storing/Saving a dictionary even after excel is closed

Tags: vba, excel, cell, insert-into

I am having a dictionary, that holds userkey -> username references. (I am using it to store the user name after looking it up in the windows directory based on the current userkey, because I assume it is a very slow process and want to improve the performance)

If I got it right on my searching, my dictionary gets completely cleared when I reopen the excel file, correct?

So I want to save it to one of the sheets, where I want to recreate it from on the next session. (one column should hold the userkey, the other the name).

My code runs, but does not write any values in the fields:

```
'will store the values on the rule sheets in row 4 following, columns BA and BB
Sub SaveDictToRulesSheet(dict As Object)

'startrow of list on excel sheet
startrow = 4
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
ActiveSheet.Name = "Rules"

        For Each key In dict.Keys
        Worksheets("Rules").Cells(startrow + i, "BA").Value = key
        Worksheets("Rules").Cells(startrow + i, "BB").Value = dict(key)
        i = i + 1
        Next key
i = 0
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `key` is not a valid property, so I'm surprised this runs - do you mean `keys` ?

Comment: ^^As in dict.keys

Comment: You can also shorten other bit to dict(key) and ensure your declare all your variables.

Comment: you are right, misspelled it...is fixed, but now I get a "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment (Error 450)" as result ?

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for your reply. Which variables are you talking about? Did I miss to define any?

Comment: startrow and key are not defined. Put option explicit at the top of your module.

Comment: How are you calling this sub? Can we see the line where you call this sub?

Comment: I had those defined, but somehow removing it did not make a difference so I removed it for shorter and easier to read code. Call is from the worksheet via     SaveDictToRulesSheet (dict) which passes an as object declared Dictionary named "dict". Declaring them did not help. same error.

Comment: How are you calling it from the worksheet?  do you mean a worksheet event in the worksheet code? or do you mean from a cell in the worksheet?

Comment: Hi @Scott Craner - a worksheet event (beforeSaved) in the worksheet code.

Comment: please show how you are filling the dictionary.

Comment: Function AddUserToDict(Userkey) As String
 
Dim key, val

'Adds non existing key and looks for value in directory
If Not dict.Exists(Userkey) Then
    key = Userkey: val = GetUserData(Userkey)
    dict.Add key, val
    AddUserToDict = val
End If

End Function (GetUserData returns the Username from the windows directory)

Comment: FWIW the scripting runtime has been standard issue on every single Windows box since 1998, and hasn't been updated since. Pretty safe to early-bind and have IntelliSense help you using it, I'd say.

Comment: @Mat, I changed the dict creation to Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"), what should result in early-bind, right? I have no experience with IntelliSense tbh

Comment: @VBA.starter no. Early binding means you have an actual reference to the library (tools/reference), and that you're declaring it `As Scripting.Dictionary`, not `As Object`. Regardless of whether you have a reference or not, regardless of how you're creating an instance of the object (i.e. `Set foo = New Whatever` or `Set foo = CreateObject("Some.ProgId")`), if it's declared `As Object` or `As Variant`, you don't get IntelliSense/autocomplete, and member calls are resolved at run-time, aka "late bound".

Comment: Public dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Public dictCreated As Boolean

Sub workbook_open()

'Create the Dictionary if it wasn't yet
If dictCreated <> True Then
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dictCreated = True
Else
End If @Mat'sMug This is my creation of the dict. sorry for not being able to format it better in the comments

Comment: `Sub SaveDictToRulesSheet(dict As Scripting.Dictionary)` - note, such early-bound code won't compile without a reference to the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* type library.

Comment: So should I change it to bound on runtime? And if yes how I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code bellow:

- `TestDictionaryOps()` - tests writing and reading from sheet
- `DictionaryToRange()` - writes dictionary to sheet
- `DictionaryFromRange()` - reads dictionary from sheet

Paste it in a new standard module, and run it on a new sheet (Sheet4)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestDictionaryOps()

    Dim d As Dictionary

    Set d = New Dictionary

    d("1") = "a"
    d("2") = "b"
    d("3") = "c"

    DictionaryToRange d, Sheet4

    Set d = DictionaryFromRange(Sheet4)

    If Not d Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Total Dictionary items: " & d.Count

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub DictionaryToRange(ByRef d As Dictionary, _
                             ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
                             Optional ByVal startCol As Long = 1)

    If Not d Is Nothing And Not ws Is Nothing And startCol > 0 Then

        Dim cnt As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

        cnt = d.Count
        If cnt > 0 Then
            Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, startCol + 0), ws.Cells(cnt, startCol + 0))
            Set rng2 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, startCol + 1), ws.Cells(cnt, startCol + 1))

            rng1 = Application.Transpose(d.Keys)    'write all keys to column 1
            rng2 = Application.Transpose(d.Items)   'write all items to column 2
        Else
            MsgBox "Empty Dictionary"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing Dictionary or WorkSheet"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function DictionaryFromRange(ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
                                    Optional ByVal startCol As Long = 1) As Dictionary

    If Not ws Is Nothing And startCol > 0 Then

        Dim d As Dictionary, cnt As Long, vArr As Variant, i As Long

        Set d = New Dictionary

        cnt = ws.UsedRange.Columns(startCol).Cells.Count
        vArr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, startCol), ws.Cells(cnt, startCol + 1)).Value2

        For i = 1 To cnt
            d(vArr(i, startCol)) = vArr(i, startCol + 1)
        Next

        Set DictionaryFromRange = d
    Else
        MsgBox "Missing WorkSheet"
    End If
End Function
```

---

> **Early binding (fast)**: VBA Editor -> Tools -> References -> Add **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**
>
> **Late binding (slow)**: CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

---

Comment: thank you @paul bica! You might be the hero I needed. However when pushing another value for the startCol (e.g. 27), I get an Sub out of range Runtime-error (Your code is in a separate module and I call it from the workbook)

Comment: I just realized the testCode returns a Value-count one higher than it should be imo. There are three entries in your test, but it returns 4 - can that cause the issue?

Comment: changing it by adding -1 did not help (however the correct value "3" is returned now), consistent "Sub out of range" error...?

Comment: @VBA.starter: make sure you run the test on a new (empty) sheet. I used.`Sheet1` as an example. If you create a new sheet (Sheet4 let’s say) update `TestDictionaryOps()` with Sheet4 instead of Sheet1. After you run the test Sheet4 should contain the 6 test items, and the message should show 3

Comment: ah okay, I ran it on a different one, but it was not empty, thanks!

Comment: Why would someone kick out two Procedures and a Function just to store and retrieve data on a single worksheet?  Wouldn't an Array be more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

> So I want to save it to one of the sheets, where I want to recreate it from on the next session. (one column should hold the userkey, the other the name).

Well that part seems fairly simple. What's a little confusing is where you read in your dict. You refer to it, but it's unclear to me where the values are being loaded in. I'm going to show you how I would do it. Hopefully that helps and I've understood the issue properly.

Write your dictionary columns to a blank / current workbook and save. Then create a new sub that operates something like this:

```
Sub Retrieve_Dict()
    Set wbkCSV = Workbooks.Open("Template.xlsx")
    Set wshCSV = wbkCSV.Worksheets("Rules")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    numrows = application.worksheetfunction.counta(wshCSV.Columns(27)) - 5
    numcols = 2
    set wshRange = wshCSV.Range("BA5").Resize(numrows,numcols)
    tempArray = wshRange.value

    for i = 1 to ubound(tempArray) ' Read rows, columns, send to dict.
        dict.key(tempArray(i, 1)) = tempArray(i, 2)' read values.
    Next i

    tempArray = Process(dict)  ' Func. updating dictionary values. 
    wshRange.value = tempArray
    wbkCSV.Close (True)
End Sub
```

Of course, you can make the above sub a function if you instead open the workbook outside, then pass the worksheet. The function could return as an Object / Scripting.Dictionary depending on your binding.

Also, note, I may have gotten the offset / row count wrong. But the general principle should apply, I think.

Comment: your code is recreating the dict from the columns right? This is the next step I'll have to do, right now I want to get my dict entries down in two columns (key/value) with one entry per row

Comment: Yeah, I think you're on the right track. That's what this code does. I don't know how easy it is to write to the spreadsheet from dictionaries, but I pass it back to the same array. You'll get there,  I think.

Comment: This looks like a cleaner solution to the problem.  Thanxs.